# Frequency of words in a text (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of words and would like to count the frequency of each word in a text and save that result in another column.

Data:

```
        word        frequency   
0       l’iss           
1       station         
2       américaines         
3       capsule         
4       dernier         
5       solaires            
6       fusées          
7       privé
```

Text:

> états-unis : lancement réussi pour station space x dragon    états-unis : lancement réussi pour space x dragon   la fusée falcon 9, développée par une société privée : spacex, a décollé de la station sans problème ce matin à 7h44 utc.   22 mai 2012. - prévu initialement pour samedi dernier, le lancement a été reporté à la dernière seconde, suite à la défaillance d'une valve dans un des neuf moteurs du pre\xadmier étage du lan\xadceur.   le lanceur a décollé du site de lancement du pas de tir 40 (slc-40) de la base de cape canaveral en floride, qui était autrefois utilisé pour les fusée titan iii et iv et qui a été reconverti pour ce lanceur.

I tried:

```
from collections import Counter

freq = df['word'].str.apply(Counter(text))
```

My output:

> AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'

Good output:

```
        word        frequency   
0       cape        1
1       station     2
2       américaines 0   
3       capsule     0   
4       dernier     1
5       solaires    0   
6       fusée       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the text into a counter and then fetch the results from it, using a mix of `value_counts` and `to_dict`.

```
# Assuming the text split is on \s
text_counts = pd.Series(text.split(' ')).value_counts().to_dict()
df['Frequency'] = df.word.apply(lambda x: text_counts.get(x, 0)) # In case the word doesn't exist
    word    Frequency
0   l’iss   0
1   station 2
2   américaines 0
3   capsule 0
4   dernier 0
5   solaires    0
6   fusées  0
7   privé   0
```

Another approach is using Python's native `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
text_counter = Counter(text.split())
df['Frequency'] = df.word.apply(lambda x: text_counter.get(x, 0))
```

Comment: this gives the wrong output, you're not using the text

Comment: You are absolutely right, I jumped into a conclusion. It is updated to match OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier the other way around. Start with the `Counter` object and from that build the dataframe

```
from collections import Counter

text = '''états-unis : lancement réussi pour station space x dragon états-unis : lancement réussi pour space x dragon la fusée falcon 9, développée par une société privée : spacex, a décollé de la station sans problème ce matin à 7h44 utc. 22 mai 2012. - prévu initialement pour samedi dernier, le lancement a été reporté à la dernière seconde, suite à la défaillance d'une valve dans un des neuf moteurs du pre\xadmier étage du lan\xadceur. le lanceur a décollé du site de lancement du pas de tir 40 (slc-40) de la base de cape canaveral en floride, qui était autrefois utilisé pour les fusée titan iii et iv et qui a été reconverti pour ce lanceur.'''

# naive splitting, it might be better to use regex with \b
c = Counter(text.split())

df = pd.DataFrame(list(c.items()), columns=['word', 'count'])
print(df.head())
```

Outputs

```
         word  count
0  états-unis      2
1           :      3
2   lancement      4
3      réussi      2
4        pour      5
```

You can then filter the dataframe for the words you want (or you can do the filtering while building the dataframe).

Comment: Not sure this is what OP wants, `I have a column of words and would like to count the frequency of each word in a text`. So IIUC the task is to count the words in the column, that are also in the text?

Comment: @yatu OP wants to count words in the text. It just so happens these words are already in a dataframe. I suggest to build a dataframe with all words counts then filter one dataframe from the other

Comment: Some of the words in the `DataFrame` are not included in the text to begin with, so doing it the other way around would eliminate those words.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your commas with space, then `.split()` and then use a dictionary comprehension and map that to your df.

```
import pandas as pd

text = "états-unis : lancement réussi pour station space x dragon états-unis : lancement réussi pour space x dragon la fusée falcon 9, développée par une société privée : spacex, a décollé de la station sans problème ce matin à 7h44 utc. 22 mai 2012. - prévu initialement pour samedi dernier, le lancement a été reporté à la dernière seconde, suite à la défaillance d'une valve dans un des neuf moteurs du pre\xadmier étage du lan\xadceur. le lanceur a décollé du site de lancement du pas de tir 40 (slc-40) de la base de cape canaveral en floride, qui était autrefois utilisé pour les fusée titan iii et iv et qui a été reconverti pour ce lanceur."

df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ["l’iss", 'station', "américaines", "capsule", "dernier", "solaires", "fusée", "privé"]})

text_list = text.replace(',', ' ').split()
word_counts = {i: text_list.count(i) for i in text_list}
df['frequency'] = df['word'].map(word_counts).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could summarise the word counts in a dict then use `map`:

```
text_list = text.split()
word_counts = {word: text_list.count(word) for word in text_list}
df['frequency'] = df['word'].map(word_counts).fillna(0)
```